# Is Kelly Lochbaum Ladder Filter LTI?

Tags: filters

I am a bit confused about the [Kelly Lochbaum](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Singing_Kelly_Lochbaum_Vocal_Tract.html) [Ladder Filter](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Conventional_Ladder_Filters.html). Image below [taken from here.](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/SMAC03S/Kelly_Lochbaum_Vocal_Tract_Model.html)

[image]

My question is, is this an LTI (linear time-invariant) filter? I thought that it was LTI, but I am not sure anymore.

Comment: Set M = 2 for example. Can you derive the transfer function? If yes, then your system is LTI.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the graph consists only of delays, add/subtract and multiply-with-a-constant, then the system will be LTI.

In this case, if the coefficients $k_1 ... k_m$ don't change with time, the system is LTI.

Answer (score 0):

Is it also always an allpass filter?
I made an implementation of the ladder filter but I found that the fft always looks the same. (unless I sum it with the "clean" signal, than a kind of comb filtering is happening).

I am not sure about this, but I am wondering what the purpose is of the ladder filter if it is only "just" an allpass filter.
I found out that it is interesting to modulate the k coefficients.